# How do I use pl/sql in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to create pl/sql blocks in mysql.

How do I create pl/sql blocks and make procedures, functions, triggers etc.

I'm happy to see detailed answers, tutorials or links.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/) site there is a good book from O'reilly

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100896